# How do you program the right analog stick of a controller in JInput?

Tags: java, controllers

I have the **Left Analog Stick** programmed and accepting input (moving a character around). (`getCompassDir()` returns the values of the cardinal directions and `NONE` means the stick isn't touched):

```
// Left Analog Stick
public int getLeftAnalogStickDir() {
    // return the (x,y) analog stick compass direction
    if ((xAxisIdx == -1) || (yAxisIdx == -1)) {
        System.out.println("(x,y) axis data unavailable");
        return NONE;
    } else
        return getCompassDir(xAxisIdx, yAxisIdx);
}
```

This works perfectly. Now when trying to program the **Right Analog Stick** of the controller, I use the same code as above, but instead, I replaced `xAxisIdx` and `yAxisIdx` with `zAxisIdx` and `rzAxisIdx` (the x, y value of the right stick). The problem is that its not reading the input like the left Analog Stick.

Does anyone know why the right analog stick isnt working? I followed the tutorial from this book:

**Pro Java 6 3D Game Development: Java 3D, JOGL, JInput and JOAL APIs**

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "doesn't work" means?